# Fragment and back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, back

I have a problem with the back/up button in a Fragment.
I have an Activity in which I have some fragments. In one Fragment, that I call "1", I have a list view. When I click on any item it goes to another fragment "2". 
I need functionality such that the back/up button only works in Fragment 2 but not in Fragment 1.

Is there a way this can be done?
I have tried this in the Activity, but I don't understand how can this help:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

When i change from fragment 1 to fragment 2 i have this code:

```
  fragment = new MaterialesFragment();
  FragmentManager fragmentManager3 = getFragmentManager();
  fragmentManager3.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).addToBackStack("tagMateriales").commit();
```

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: from where to where you want? Fragment2 to 1? its not clear

Comment: Add the onCreate of your activity. And how do you add the second fragment? Do you use replace? Could you give more details?

Comment: Just use `.addToBackStack(null)` on your transaction which switches to fragment 2 before committing it.

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati i first go to Fragment 1 to fragment 2, then that section ends i want to go back to fragment 1 so i can select another item from the list view, but i dont want the back button to be active for fragment 1, just for fragment 2. Is it clear? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `addToBackStack()` method on the `FragmentTransaction` object you use to replace the fragment2 into the screen:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment2).addToBackStack("tagHere").commit();
```

You can pass `null` as the parameter if you don't need the actual tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code for your 'fragment 2'

```
public void showFragmentWithoutStack(Fragment fragment, String tag, int id) {
     FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
     transaction.add(id, fragment, tag);
     transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Where `tag` might be String class name, id of your root view in activity (Because fragment should appear on the top layer).

Comment: thanks for answering, can you tell me please where do i have to add this? thanks :)

Comment: I would create that method In your Activity, for example BaseActivity. In your activity you should have that above method. In you fragment you should have method `protected void showFragmentWithoutStack(Fragment fragment, String tag, int id) {
        ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).showFragmentWithoutStack(fragment, tag, id);
    }` You should control fragments from activity

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `onBackPressed()` method override in the Activity as you have in the question, you also need to add this to your Fragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case android.R.id.home:
        // Assuming MainActivity is the Activity subclass name
        if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onBackPressed();
        }
        return true;
      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In order to show/hide the back button, add these methods to your Activity:

```
public void showUpButton() {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

public void hideUpButton() {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}
```

Then, when you want to show or hide the back/up button from a Fragment, call these methods.

In your case, you could hide the back/up button from `onResume()` in Fragment 1:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).hideUpButton();
```

And then show it in `onResume()` in Fragment 2:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).showUpButton();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i add this in my fragment 2 , but it`s happening the same (both fragments can go back with the "back button") i just want the fragment 2 to have this functionality and fragment 1 will have it like "blocked".

Comment: The back button arrow now appears, but when i clicked on it appears the menu i have. Can you help in which part i have to call the Fragment 1 ? thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @StephySamaniego It sounds like you need to separate out the cases in your `onOptionsItemSelected()` method.  Notice the `case android.R.id.home`, you need that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of way to do this job. In my opinion the most elegant is the following. I would isolate the logic in each component. Every fragment implements an interface like "IBackHandler" that allows activity and fragment to communicate. In the activity `onBackPressed` asks first the fragment (if it is instantiated) what to do and then acts.

The interface:

```
public interface IBackHandler {
    boolean doBack();
}
```

The fragment that implements that interface and put its logic to handle the back button pressed:

```
public class YourFragment1 extends YourBaseFragment implements IBackHandler {
      // your code
      @Override
      public boolean doBack() {
           // return true means that you have done your stuff
           //and you don't want 'super.onBackPressed()' to be called
           return true; // this means do nothing
      }
 }
```

Fragment 2:

```
 public class YourFragment2 extends YourBaseFragment implements IBackHandler {
      // your code
      @Override
      public boolean doBack() {
           return false; //this means: call 'super.onBackPressed()'
      }
 }
```

Your Activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends YourBaseActivity {
     //your code
     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
         Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragment);
    if (currentFragment instanceof IBackHandler) {
        if (!((IBackHandler) currentFragment).doBack()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    } else
        super.onBackPressed();
     }
}
```

You could think that this is overengineering but I can reassure you that in this way you'll always be able to control what'happening in your flow.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem use this code when change fragment:

```
String fragmentIndexString="fragmenttwo";//or fragmentone something
transaction.addToBackStack();
```

This is full code in Activity:

```
FirstFragment firstFragment; // my first fragment
SecondFragment secondFragment; // my second fragment
public static String FIRST="asfasgasg"; //first fragment index
public static String SECOND="gsadgsagd"; //second fragment index
...
/* u can change fragment by using setFragment funiction */
public void setFragment(String page){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    switch (page){
        case FIRST:
            if(firstFragment==null) firstFragment= SettingFragment.newInstance();
            if (!firstFragment.isAdded()) {
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, firstFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(INDEX);
                transaction.commit();
            } else {
                transaction.show(firstFragment);
            }
            break;
        case SECOND:
            if(secondFragment==null) secondFragment= SettingFragment.newInstance();
            if (!secondFragment.isAdded()) {
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, secondFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(INDEX);
                transaction.commit();
            } else {
                transaction.show(secondFragment);
            }
            break;
        default:
            setFragment(INDEX);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>1){
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. When i change from fragment 1 to fragment 2 i have this code:                            fragment = new MaterialesFragment();
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager3 = getFragmentManager();
                            fragmentManager3.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).addToBackStack("tagMateriales").commit();